# Too Few Paramters. Expected 1

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a bit of VBA code that generates an HTML report based on the contents of a query. The query date is determined via the contents of a box using the following criteria.

```
 Forms![frmImport]![Flash]
```

When I have it set that way, it gives me the Too Few Parameters error. If I set to criteria to say, 2/20/2013, it works just fine. I'm assuming this has something to do with the way VBA interprets query criteria.

Below is the part of my code that VBA seems to not like.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim QUERY As DAO.Recordset

Set QUERY = db.OpenRecordset("qryFlash")
```

I'm not sure if there is something more I have to add to the Set line in order for VBA to play nice with this query.

Comment: show the full SQL query, or at least the full WHERE condition--you've some sort of error when referring to the form textbox from inside your query (maybe the name "flash" isn't the name of the textbox, or the form is closed when you run the query, or ?)

Comment: WHERE (((qryMidDay1.Profile) Like "*ABCD") AND ((tblLibrary.Date)=[Forms]![frmImport]![Flash]));

The textbox name is right and I've had the form open everytime I've ran it.

Comment: While the form is open go to the VBA editor, open the immediate window (if it isn't open) and type: ? [Forms]![frmImport]![Flash] Make sure it looks like a date.  If it does then make sure tblLibrary.Date is actually type datetime.

Comment: Everything looks to be in order in that regard.

Comment: Have you referenced the Microsoft DAO Object Library?

Comment: Yes, all references are in order.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim prm As DAO.Parameter
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryFlash")
For Each prm In qdf.Parameters
    prm.Value = Eval(prm.Name)
Next prm
Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset)
```

Comment: That does not seem to quite work. I am using a number of .RecordCounts and .MoveFirst commands in the code in order to build the report correctly and they do not seem to play well with this setup.

Comment: You didn't mention what the problem is.  Please give as much information as you can about what specifically isn't working they way you want.  Note you can always just build the SQL string instead of opening the recordset from a stored query in which case you won't have thee parameter issue.  Also if the result set is somewhat small and if you don't need it to be updatable dbOpenSnapshot is better.

Comment: That's actually what I ended up doing. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Ended up simply building the SQL string instead of using a query. Solved my issue.